# Drupal - MENU_LOCAL_TASK - keep ID

Tags: drupal, tabs

Since days I'm fighting this problem: I have some links like this: /mymodule/detail/[ID_product] 
in a block. Following this, I want to display different aspects of the specific product in tabs - alway keeping the ID_product given by the primary link.

What I have is this:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
$items['mymodule/detail'] = array(
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
'page callback' => 'mymodule_page',
'page arguments' => array ('aspect1', 1),
'access callback' => TRUE,
);
$items['mymodule/detail/aspect1'] = array(
'title' => 'Tab 1: aspect1',
'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
'page arguments' => array (1),
'access callback' => TRUE,
 );
$items['mymodule/detail/aspect2'] = array(
'title' => 'Tab 2: aspect2',
'page callback' => 'mymodule_page',
'page arguments' => array (1),
'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
'access callback' => TRUE,
);
return $items;
}
```

Is there an good way to distribute the product-ID to the tabs?

Comment: why dont you use % after the "aspect1" and "aspect2" to pass dynamic id

Answer (score 0):

I am new at Drupal but if I'm right, this way I could manage the ID comming with the first call. But how to transfer the ID through the tab-links? The tab-menu-link should contain/deliver the ID - that's my problem.